# Empty string should be NULL when converting to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

Consider the following TSQL code:

```
declare @a nvarchar(500) = N''
select try_convert(float, @a)
```

The output is:

```
0
```

I need the output to be NULL.

I can do this:

```
declare @a nvarchar(500) = N''
select case @a
           when '' then null
           else try_convert(float, @a)
       end
```

and it works just fine.

However, this is just a mock-up. In my real life scenario, instead of `@a`, there are over 200 `NVARCHAR(500)` columns, either floats or zero length strings. I need a quick way of converting zero-length strings to NULL (and everything else to float), possibly without having to build 200 separate CASE statements.

Comment: For a zero-length string there is an implicit conversion from `varchar` to `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really thrilled with relying the rather inexplicable differences between `try_parse()` and `try_convert()`/`try_cast()`.  Instead, I would go for:

```
try_convert(float, nullif(@a, ''))
```

This also has the advantage of being quite explicit in what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Try_parse instead

```
declare @a nvarchar(500) = N''
select try_parse( @a as float)
```

returns

```
NULL
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/LRCQSR37033)**</kbd>